# Jquery & Datepicker - How to protect the value of a textfield from user changes? (and automatically rerendered the value of the calendar)?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, textfield

Sorry for this simple question but I am really a noob and didn't find what I want in the jquery documentation.

Here is the story:

I have a text field in a form populated by a calendar in jquery (datepicker). 
I would like to "protect" this textbox. in other word if the user wants to change the value in the textbox (deleting or adding something), the value generated by the calendar is automatically re-rendered.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML has the readonly attribute for textareas and input fields.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Users cannot change me" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$('#textfield-id').keydown(function(){
   if($(this).val() == '') {
      //get value from calendar again
      var calText = $('#calendar').val();
      $(this).val(calText);
   }
});
```